# How to solve 'Run Time Error: 424 Object Required' in distance calculation code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I copied this code from https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/vb and i am trying to use it in ms-access to calculate the distance between two sets of latitude and longitude (which are in textboxes). Preferably, I'd like to show the result in a subform but i am not sure if this is possible. If not, I'd like to insert the result of calculation into a textbox by clicking a button. New to coding, any help appreciated.

code with error line
[image: code with error line]

rest of code
[image: rest of code]

Comment: Could you add your code as text?

Comment: `response` isn't defined anywhere. Was this copied from ASP classic code?

Answer (score -2):

The link in question is VB code. VB is similar to VBA. Will have to modify. Remove the response.write lines or use Debug.Print instead.

Function can be called by expression in textbox ControlSource property. Result will not be saved to record.
`=distance([txtJobLat], -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") & " Miles"`

Event code can set value of textbox. If textbox is bound to field, calculated result will be saved to record. Click event relies on user. If you want to make sure value is saved to record, use some other event to automate, such as form BeforeUpdate or Close.
`Me.textboxname = distance(Me.txtJobLat, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") & " Miles"`